# Detect multiple elongations in text

Tags: python, regex

I am doing some tasks on NLP. So, I need to detect multiple elongations and single elongation in text.

**Example of Single elongation:** simpleeeeeeeeeee

**Example of Multiple elongations:**  Goooooodddddddd

I have managed the following code to detect elongation in text.

```
def find_total_elongations(str):
    regex = re.compile(r"(.)\1{2}")
    list = [word for word in str.split() if regex.search(word)]
    return len(list)
```

**Sample Input:**
 Whyyyyyyyy arrrrrrreeeeee youuuuuuuu sooooooooooo serrrrrrrrrrriiiiiiious ?

**Sample Output:**

Single Elongation: ["Whyyyyyyyy","youuuuuuuu", "sooooooooooo"]

Multiple Elongation: ["arrrrrrreeeeee","serrrrrrrrrrriiiiiiious"]

How can I change the above code to detect multiple elongation and single elongation separately?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it a little bit:

```
\w*(.)\1{1}\w*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `itertools.groupby`. Example from the docs:

```
# [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and detect any groups where the length is greater than 1 and then ensure theres no more than one group

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: sum(1 for _ in x[1]) > 1, groupby("goodoo")))) > 1
```